# ng-angular repeat filter equal and not equal to

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

Im using an ng-repeat to make table of all axam slots as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="id in exams | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:{licencetype:searchExam, studentId:assignfilter}">
```

Free exam-slot lines contain "ex_slot" in the field studentId. I would like to filter this table using radiobuttons. 
On top of this table i'm using radiobuttons to filter this table.

```
<label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="assignfilter" value="ex_slot">
<?php echo $lang['LBL_NOT_ASSIGNED']; ?>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="assignfilter" value="">
    <?php echo $lang['LBL_ASSIGNED']; ?>
</label>
```

I cant seem to get the filter to work.
One radio button should filter "equal to ex_slot"
The other butto should filter "not equal to ex_slot".
Is this possible with the angular filter option in ng-repeat?

Comment: Have you tried to assing "assignfilter" with some value (like "") in the controller? You can also set a name to both radio buttons.

Comment: Apparently it is as simple as : <label>
           <input type="radio" ng-model="assignfilter" value="ex_slot">
           <?php echo $lang['LBL_NOT_ASSIGNED'];?>
          </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <label>
           <input type="radio" ng-model="assignfilter" value="!ex_slot">
           <?php echo $lang['LBL_ASSIGNED']; ?>
          </label>

Comment: I see you asked a lot of question without marking one as right. Please mark the right answer in your questions. I would help other users and its how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said whether any part of this is working.  From the code you show, it looks like the filter to show the free slots should be working.  Is this true?

If so, the following change should work

```
<label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="assignfilter" value="ex_slot">
<?php echo $lang['LBL_NOT_ASSIGNED']; ?>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="assignfilter" value="!ex_slot">
    <?php echo $lang['LBL_ASSIGNED']; ?>
</label>
```

should work.  According to the angular.filter documentation:

> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on
>   objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"}
>   predicate will return an array of items which have property name
>   containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property
>   name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any
>   property of the object or its nested object properties. That's
>   equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described
>   above. **The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !.
>   For example {name: "!M"} predicate will return an array of items which
>   have property name not containing "M".**

[Documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)